# rails count records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let say i have the following car loop and i want to display 4 cars on one row and then create a new row etc.

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <% @cars.each do |car| %>
        <td><%= car.name %></td>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So i looks like this:

car1 car2 car3 car4

car5 car6 car7 car8

car9 car10 ... ...
...

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<table>
  <% @cars.each_slice(4) do |cars| %>
    <tr>
      <% cars.each do |car| %>
        <td><%= car.name %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Adding a class to last `td` in a row:

```
<table>
  <% @cars.each_slice(4) do |cars| %>
    <tr>
      <% cars.each do |car| %>
        <td <%= "class='my_class'" if car == cars.last %>>
          <%= car.name %>
        </td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Great! What if I want to add a class to the last TD before another row is added?

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the [each_slice method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001514) from Enumerable, an example like so:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].each_slice(4).to_a
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
```

So your code would be like:

```
<table>
  <% @cars.each_slice(4) do |cars| %>
    <tr>
      <% cars.each do |c| %>
        <td><%= c.name %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Point is, always check out the [Enumerable page](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) for things like this. Ruby provides amazing methods like this!